# Java Script Function is working well for a specific regex but does not work as expected in another one

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JavaScript function which is working well as a 4 digit separator by spaces.

Here is my regex I tested with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/K4WXc/2/

```
LB\d{2}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}
```

However, when I put my new regex for iban, it does not work as the former one
did.

```js
function space(el, after) {
  after = after || 4;
  var v = el.value.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/, ''),
    reg = new RegExp(".{" + after + "}", "g")
  el.value = v.replace(reg, function(a, b, c) {
    return a + ' ';
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('iban');
  el.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    space(this, 4);
  });
})
// my assigned var is like 
//  var v = el.value.replace(/LB\d{2}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4} 
// [ ]\d{4}/g, ''),
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="iban">iban</label>
<input id="iban" type="text" name="iban" />
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to achieve, but the original code pretty much removes anything but numbers and upper case characters and then add spaces after each `after` characters.

Your question suggests that you want to validate some format. Can you clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: my question is to apply the second regex for iban to match a case like LB12 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234

Comment: have you posted code that works or doesn't work?

Comment: i posted the working code,and at last a just showed how i used the new regex i want

Comment: Your `reg` is `/.{4}/g` and you pass a callback method as the replacement argument, why? You just need `el.value = v.replace(reg, '$& ')`. Now, what is the goal with the `var v = el.value.replace(/LB\d{2}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}/g, '')`? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to replace my regex with the one /[^\dA-Z]/ my regex is the one you are asking about here is the result i want  LB12 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234

Comment: That is, if a user types in `LB12123412341234123412341234`, it should get reformatted to `LB12 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234 1234` on the fly? So, `LB\d{2}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}` is the old regex that you want to replace with the new code posted above?

Comment: yes that's what i am trying to do and force teh user to begin with LB and max length is 28 characters and insert spaces each 4 characters

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/t3rLg850/1/

Comment: Thanks, but it accepts  another letters than Lb and it accepts Lb in the middle string

Comment: anyway , i will check the matching on the backend its ok , thanks

Comment: So, does it work? It allows a lof because it is not a validation, it is a re-formatting code now. Shall post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the former regex:

```
el.value.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/, '')
```

This is your idea:

```
el.value.replace(/LB\d{2}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}[ ]\d{4}/g, '')
```

It is not working because you fail to understand what the code was trying to do. That original line has one purpose: To remove all characters that are not digits, or upper-case letters. So, `aA!@1b2345` becomes `A12345` only. The next part `reg = new RegExp(".{" + after + "}", "g")` is used with `v.replace` to add spaces after some number of characters (as specified in `after`). That means `A12345` becomes `A123 45`, and is written back to the element.

You could try this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/aoLrb41p/

Comment: Thanks for your time @James Wilkins ,you are right, i should have given it more time